# JQuery - Object doesn't support property or method toLowerCase

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I've been struggling with this problem for a week now. This is the situation:
I've been working on moving a SharePoint application out of SharePoint and as it's own website. Our SharePoint version is 2007 and we need to upgrade it. So my boss has asked me to move this out.

I already worked on one SharePoint application, made it its' own website, it works fine. But this one is causing me so much trouble!

I get this error EVERY TIME I run the program:
[image]

This is not like any thing else on the internet. I've searched and read so many posts on SO and so many other forums, but it is not the same. The application breaks during runtime in a line in `jquery-1.8.2.js`. I did not write this. I did not change this. This was on my list of scripts when I created a new ASP .Net project.

Here is the line that causes the error:

```
acceptData: function( elem ) {
    var noData = elem.nodeName && jQuery.noData[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ];
    // nodes accept data unless otherwise specified; rejection can be conditional
    return !noData || noData !== true && elem.getAttribute("classid") === noData;
}
```

I am a beginner in ASP .Net and have absolutely no idea which direction to go. Here is what I've already tried:

1. I opened my first application that I moved out of SharePoint and tried to replicate exactly what I did there here.
2. I checked my packages, my references, and every thing there is to check.
3. I tried running the application on Chrome instead of IE. The application does not break and point out the line causing the error. BUT, if I open developer tools on Chrome, I still see that error. Here is what it looks like in Chrome:
   [image]

Again, any suggestions of changing the code is not what I am looking for. This is not my code. I am almost certain it has something to do with some references or just the basic structure of my application.

Please ask me if you want more information. I just don't even know what to share to make it easier for you guys to help me. Let me know what information you'd like and I'd share it.

Thank you.

**Edit 1:**
`console.log(elem.nodeName)` results this:

```
#document
function(a) {
    return a.nodeName.toLowerCase()
}
```

Comment: what is the type of elem?

Comment: do `console.log(elem.nodeName)` just after `acceptData: function( elem ) {` and show us what you got

Comment: `Again, any suggestions of changing the code is not what I am looking for.`  I'm not entirely sure what this references.  You keep saying it is not your code.  Are you saying you don't want to modify the script in any way to fix the issue?  Or are you saying you believe the script is fine, but your invocation of it is wrong?

Comment: It's a jQuery bug. Why it happens seems to be due to window.nodeName being defined to this element (which doesn't have a toLowerCase method as it's an element) by the fact the element with this id exists. Can you change your jQuery version to 2.02+ and check ?

Comment: Alive to Die: I have updated my answer with what you asked for.
Taplar: Yes that is what I think. This same file with the same contents exists in my first application and it did not cause problems. My current project is IDENTICAL to my first but there are problems. I feel like it has to do with my project structure. References, a line on web.config, something of that sort

Comment: Tushar: I will give it a shot and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Tushar That did it!! If you want to post your reply as an answer, I can mark it as the answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: @CrazyCucumber awesome! happy to help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a jQuery bug. Why it happens seems to be due to window.nodeName being defined to this element (which doesn't have a toLowerCase method as it's an element) by the fact the element with this id exists.

Change your jQuery version to 2.02+ and check